# Semantic UI accordion overlap position fixed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I am a beginner so please bear with me. I have an accordion and a position fixed element at the bottom of the sidebar. My problem is that when the accordion is opened, it overlaps the position fixed element. Also, I would like that it would not be scrollable past the position fixed element at the bottom. I've tried sorts of positioning of the divs but still a no go. Can somebody please enlighten me. Thank you!

```js
$(function () {
 $('.ui.accordion').accordion();
});
```

```css
.ui.vertical.footer.segment {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="ui sidebar vertical left menu overlay borderless visible">
                <div class="ui accordion">
                    <a class="title item">
                        <i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i> Menu <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div class="content">
                        <a class="item active" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i> Content
                        </a>
                        <a class="item active" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i> Content
                        </a>
                        <a class="item active" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i> Content
                        </a>
                        <a class="item active" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i> Content
                        </a>
                        <a class="item active" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i> Content
                        </a>
                        <a class="item active" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i> Content
                        </a>
                        <a class="item active" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i> Content
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="ui vertical footer segment" id="test">
                    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> Search
                    <button class="ui button">
                        Go
                    </button>
                </div>
                </div>
                
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you might consider increasing `z-index` for the accordion or reducing `z-index` for the search bar.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam hello sir thanks for answering. That is working but my problem is that if the window is resized, it is still scrollable to the bottom. What is the best way to prevent that?

Comment: You can use `scroll` property in css and set it to `none`.

Comment: can you please write one more time what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov what I wanted is that it will not be scrollable past the fixed element. As you can see on the fiddle, it is still scrollable on that part and it overlaps the fixed positioned element.

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov the fixed position element should stay at the bottom always and the scroll will not overlap at the fixed positioned element regardless if the browser's window height is resized.

Comment: @AkanshGulati thank you sir for answering. I'll try that one.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any way css clean enough to solve this problem. So I resolved to look for a jQuery solution. I had a little trouble finding the uses of call back on Semantic UI. in short I spent time, I hope it will earn me some points, especially since I have documented extensively with the comment code.

The operation be good in the snippet only in full screen mode, because I use `$ (window) .resize (function ().`

Here is the result:

```js
$(function () {

var oUser3233787 = {                    // variables group name of User3233787 problem.
    $mn : $('.ui.accordion'),           // jQuery Menu objet
    mnC : $('.ui.accordion').height(),  // height Menu close
    mnO : 0,                            // height Menu open (unknow for the moment)
    Fmn : false,                        // Flag menu open / close
    foH : $('#test').outerHeight(),     // room size of footer height
    mnX : $(window).height() - this.foH // room place max for the menu, deppending on window height
};

oUser3233787.$mn.accordion({ 
    onOpen: function( v1, v2 ) {        // open menu event;  (v1, v2 documented nowhere...? )
        with (oUser3233787) {
            if (mnO == 0)               // if menu open hight is unknow
                mnO = $mn.height();     // get this one

            $mn.height(mnO);            // set menu hight to open size
            Fmn = true;                 // set Flag = menu is open

            if (mnO > mnX)              // if menu hight is out of room place
                $mn.height(mnX);        // set the menu higt fit to it
        }    
    },
    onClose: function( v1, v2 ) {       // close menu event
        with (oUser3233787) {
            $mn.height(mnC);            // set menu hight to closed size
            Fmn = false;                // set Flag = menu is not open
        }
    }
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    with (oUser3233787) {
        mnX = $(window).height() - foH;  // keep this height for the oUser3233787 group
        if (Fmn) {                       // if menu is open
            if (mnO > mnX)               // and if his open heigh is too big
                $mn.height(mnX);         // reduce them at room height
            if (mnO < mnX)               // but if there is enough room 
                $mn.height(mnO);         // restore his open high complete height
        }
    }
});

}); // jQuery
```

```css
.ui.vertical.footer.segment {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.ui.accordion {
 overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="ui sidebar vertical left menu overlay borderless visible">
                <div class="ui accordion">
                    <a class="title item">
                        <i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i> Menu <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div class="content">
                        <a class="item active" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i> Content
                        </a>
                        <a class="item active" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i> Content
                        </a>
                        <a class="item active" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i> Content
                        </a>
                        <a class="item active" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i> Content
                        </a>
                        <a class="item active" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i> Content
                        </a>
                        <a class="item active" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i> Content
                        </a>
                        <a class="item active" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i> Content
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="ui vertical footer segment" id="test">
                    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> Search &nbsp;
                    <button class="ui button">
                        Go
                    </button>
                </div>
                </div>
                
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.js"></script>
```